# jQuery get element attribute from nested element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in a situation as follows:

```
<span class="inputgrp">
  <span class="additem">

  </span>
</span>
<input type="text" avl="abc">
```

I'm trying to get the value of the attribute **avl** from the input with a click event on class="**inputgrp**"

I have tried with:

```
$(".additem").click(function () {
  var v = $(this).parent().find("input:text").attr("avl")
})
```

and

```
$(".inputgrp").click(function () {
  var v = $(this).prev("span").next("input:text").attr("avl")
})
```

But without success. Would appreciate some guide as I have no clue what I am dong wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(".inputgrp").click(function() {

  alert($(this).next("input:text").attr("data-avl"))

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="inputgrp">
  <span class="additem">
1
  </span>
</span>
<input type="text" data-avl="abc">
```

1. Use data attribute since avl is not a valid attribute
2. use `.next()` since input is next to the click element

Answer (score 0):

`.find` searches for children of the current element. The `input` is not a `child` but a `sibling` of `.inputgrp`

```
$('.inputgrp').on('click',function() {
    var v = $(this).siblings('input[data-avl]').attr('data-avl');
});
```

- Use `data-avl` as an attribute to make it valid.
- Use the `.sibling()` function to select any of the siblings
- If the `input` element is always going to be the next element, use the `.next()` function

Answer (score 0):

use a `data-avl=""` attribute on your html input element  and in jQuery use `.data('avl')` to get the value of the attribute

```
$(".inputgrp").click(function() {

  alert($(this).next("input:text").data("avl"));

})
```